# How to check if parent element has a child element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a parent element which includes child element. But the child element appears only when the button click.

Initial parent element:

```
<div class="parent">
   <!--v-if-->
</div>
```

When the button is clicked:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

So I want to see if the parent element has a child element or not. How can I do it with javascript?

Comment: `document.querySelector(".parent > .child")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[el.hasChildNodes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_haschildnodes.asp)- This can do the job but it will also count the non-element nodes.
[el.children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children)- This includes only element nodes.

```js
let parent1 = document.getElementById("parent1");
let parent2 = document.getElementById("parent2");
let parent3 = document.getElementById("parent3")

console.log('Parent1 has child - ', parent1.hasChildNodes());
console.log('Parent1 has child - ', Boolean(parent1.children.length));

console.log('Parent2 has child - ', parent2.hasChildNodes());
console.log('Parent2 has child - ', Boolean(parent2.children.length));

console.log('Parent3 has child - ', parent3.hasChildNodes());
console.log('Parent3 has child - ', Boolean(parent3.children.length));
```

```html
<!-- parent 1 -->
<div id="parent1"></div>

<!-- parent 2 -->
<div id="parent2">
  <div id="child1"></div>
</div>

<!-- parent 3 -->
<div id="parent3">
  <!-- comment -->
</div>
```

Comment: The parent element shown in the question **does** have child nodes in the initial state (two text nodes and a comment node), so this would always say `true`. The only reason the snippet in your answer works is you removed those non-element child nodes.

Comment: Yes, I edited the answer with the difference. I didn't notice the comment element in the question.

Answer (score 1):

That element does start out with child nodes (two text nodes and a comment node), just no *element* children.

If you want to know if it has any *element* children, you can use [`firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/firstElementChild), which will be `null` if the element doesn't have any child elements, or the first child element if it does.

```js
const x = document.querySelector(".parent");

console.log(`Before: ${!!x.firstElementChild}`);

// Emulate replacing the comment node with an element node
const div = document.createElement("div");
div.className = "child";
x.replaceChild(div, x.childNodes[1]);

console.log(`After:  ${!!x.firstElementChild}`);
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <!--v-if-->
</div>
```